# How did Deathbolt (Arrow/The Flash) become a meta-human?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-flash, arrow, arrowverse

On TV Show "Arrow", season 3 episode 18, we were introduced to a new villain Jake Simmons (Deathbolt). After his capture, they did a cross-over scene with "The Flash" with Ray and Cisco talking over the fact that Jake Simmons wasn't in Central city on the night the particle accelerator exploded, which made it unknown as to how he became a meta-human. But this was never mentioned after.

His second appearance was on "The Flash", season 1, episode 22, where he was killed by Captain Cold, like discarded.

So, what exactly happened?
Did they discarded his story?
How did he become a meta-human? Any cross-references with comics?

Comment: He's prolly from earth 2 and was introduced before season 2 of the flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DC Comics character Deathbolt was given his powers through being the subject of experiments conducted by a character called the Ultra-Humanite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathbolt

As the Wikipedia article notes, his introduction to the CW universe was likely intended to demonstrate, much like the comics universe, that metahumans have a great variety of origins.